# How to upload photo in Django

Tags: python, html, django, image, model

I have a small problem with django here.
I want to upload a photo of one product in production and want that this photo be shown to me in homepage.

Here is the `Product` class in `models.py`:

```
class Produto(models.Model):

    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='mywebsite/staticfiles/static')


    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.nome)
```

In my `settings.py`, I've set these variables:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)
```

And in my htm page:

```
{% for produto in produtos %}
    <li>
        <div class="col-md-3 biseller-column">
            <a href="single.html">
                <img src="{{produto.foto.url}}"/>
            </a>
            <div class="ad-info">
                <h5>{{produto.nome}}</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

So, I get my upload and when I upload via web browser the photo appears on staticfiles/static but in not in the site. In web page appears the follow:

[image: Capture of my screen]

Could someone help me?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't set your media root or added the url configurations hence they're not being served. You can check out how to set these up at [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/)

Comment: I was typping MEDIA_ROOT with the same as STATIC_ROOT instead. But the django in general block it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your template.
Try `{{ produto.foto.image.url }}` instead of `{{ produto.foto.url }}` to access to image file url.